# RewardActivity ads Setting error solution

Tags: java, android, ads

i make a smal quiz app and i create Reward activiy in app and add 5 rewarded ads in activity.
so when user click on first ads then rewarded ads play then then green tickmark show. same as other ads. but in java code when i implement ads code then error show . can any body help me how to set rewarded video ads properly. i am attaching rewarded activity and xml code here . please please help me. (i am using firebasefirestore ).

> ///when i add coins in fieldvalue.increment then error show.
> 'show(android.app.Activity, com.google.android.gms.ads.rewarded.RewardedAdCallback)' in 'com.google.android.gms.ads.rewarded.RewardedAd' cannot be applied to '(android.app.Activity, anonymous com.google.android.gms.ads.OnUserEarnedRewardListener)'

```
public class RewardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ActivityRewardBinding binding;
FirebaseFirestore database;
private RewardedAd mRewardedAd;
UserDetail userDetail;
int coins= 0;
String currentUid;
int COINS = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    binding = ActivityRewardBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView( binding.getRoot() );
    loadAd();

    database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    currentUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
    database.collection( "Users" )
            .document( FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid() )
            .get().addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            userDetail = documentSnapshot.toObject( UserDetail.class );
            // coins show methods below
            binding.coins.setText( String.valueOf( userDetail.getCoins()));

            //binding.coins.setText( userDetail.getCoins() + "" );

        }
    } );

    binding.video1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mRewardedAd !=null) {
                Activity activityContext = RewardActivity.this;
                mRewardedAd.show( activityContext, new OnUserEarnedRewardListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {
                        loadAd();
                        coins = coins + 200;
                        database.collection( "Users" )
                                .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid() )
                                .update( "coins", FieldValue.increment( coins ) );
                        binding.video1Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.check);


                    }
                } );
            }
        }
    } );
    

}
void loadAd(){
    mRewardedAd = new RewardedAd( this , "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917" );

    mRewardedAd.loadAd( new AdRequest.Builder().build() , new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onRewardedAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
            super.onRewardedAdFailedToLoad( i );
        }
    });
}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbs2i.png)

Comment: anybody can help me?

Comment: no body reply.....